# Test Login Utility

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a utility that will check if our site is down. The only way to do that is to login and if nothing is returned then the site is down. I've gotten it to the point where it will auto login, but not sure how to get it to check if the login was successful. Anyone got an idea?

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>test Login</TITLE>
        <script>
            function loginForm() {
                document.myform.action = "http://example.com";
                document.myform.submit();
            }
        </script>

    </HEAD>
    <BODY onLoad="loginForm()">
        <form action="http://example.com" class="uni-form" method="post" name="_58_fm"> 
            <input name="_58_redirect" type="hidden" value="">  
            <input id="_58_rememberMe" name="_58_rememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">   
            <fieldset class="block-labels"> <div class="ctrl-holder">   
                    <label for="_58_login">Email Address</label>    
                    <input name="_58_login" type="text" value="emailaccount@email.com"> 
                </div><div class="ctrl-holder"> <label for="_58_password">Password</label>  
                    <input id="_58_password" name="_58_password" type="password" value="UberSecretPassword">    
                    <span id="_58_passwordCapsLockSpan" style="display: none;">Caps Lock is on.</span>  
                </div><div class="button-holder">   
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In">   
                </div></fieldset>
        </FORM>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('submit').click();
            }
            function checker(){
                if(<-- what to put here --> ="  You are signed in as "){
                    // Not sure what to put here
                }
            }
        </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: If your site is down, how does the page load in the first place?

Comment: does a failed login take you back to this page? then set a cookie and check if that cookie is present on page load - if it's there, a previous login failed. if you DON'T come back to this page, then it's pointless to put anything here - code which is never executed is useless.

Comment: Could you instead use a service like uptimerobot.com?

Comment: @j08691 It gives you a Glass Fish error page.

Comment: @pgmann I tried that, but we need it to always go past the login page to check